# Erroneous depiction by use of `\draw` and `\fill` commands in PGFplots `axis` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to use table data to construct a patch surface plot. In doing so, I use `pgf/tikz`, `pgfplots`, `pgfplotstable` and the command `\edef`.

My code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{filecontents}{table.txt}
NLDefn1 NLDefn2 NLDefn3 NLDefn4 NLDefn5 NLDefn6 NLDefn7 NLDefn8 NLDefn9 NLDefn10
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   2.100000000000000e-02   4.300000000000000e-02   3.900000000000000e-02   2.000000000000000e-02
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   1.000000000000000e-02   1.750000000000000e-02   1.000000000000000e-02   5.525000000000000e-02   6.700000000000000e-02   7.325000000000000e-02   5.500000000000000e-02
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   1.333333333333333e-02   3.733333333333334e-02   1.333333333333333e-02   6.344444444444444e-02   6.811111111111111e-02   8.366666666666667e-02   6.333333333333334e-02
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   2.487500000000000e-02   5.212500000000000e-02   2.750000000000000e-02   6.018750000000000e-02   7.137499999999999e-02   8.506250000000000e-02   5.756250000000000e-02
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\fillOpacity}{0.5}
\newcommand{\textOpacity}{1}

\pgfplotsset
{   
    patchOptsA/.style={patch,mesh,patch type=triangle,gray,ultra thin},
    patchOptsB/.style={patch,patch type=triangle},
    patchOptsC/.style={patch,patch type=triangle,mesh,black},
}

\tikzset
{
    drawOpts/.style={gray,dashed,ultra thin},
    nodeOptsA/.style={black,anchor=south,fill=white,fill opacity=0.25,text opacity=1}
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   
            width=0.5*210mm,
            height=0.25*297mm,
            %yscale=?,
            axis lines=center,
            xmin=-4/sqrt(3),
            xmax=4/sqrt(3),
            xtick=\empty,
            hide x axis,
            %xlabel=$x$,
            ytick=\empty,
            hide y axis,
            %ylabel=$y$,
            zmin=0,
            zmax=0.1,
            view={215}{10},
        ]
            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(0,0,0) (-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (1/sqrt(3),-1,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn1}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(0,0,\triangleCoordAz) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordBz) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(0,0,\triangleCoordAz) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordBz) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordCz)};

            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (-2/sqrt(3),-2,0) (0,-2,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn4}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (-2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordBz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (-2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordBz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordCz)};          

            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (0,-2,0) (1/sqrt(3),-1,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordCz)};

            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (0,-2,0) (2/sqrt(3),-2,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn6}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordCz)};

            % Dashed lines and nodes of triangle.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn1}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\CoordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \draw[drawOpts] (axis cs:0,0,0)--(axis cs:0,0,\CoordZ);
            \fill[gray] (axis cs:0,0,\CoordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$1$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\CoordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \draw[drawOpts] (axis cs:{-1/sqrt(3)},-1,0)--(axis cs:{-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\CoordZ);
            \fill[gray] (axis cs:{-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\CoordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$x$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\CoordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \draw[drawOpts] (axis cs:{1/sqrt(3)},-1,0)--(axis cs:{1/sqrt(3)},-1,\CoordZ);
            \fill[gray] (axis cs:{1/sqrt(3)},-1,\CoordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$y$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn4}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\CoordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \draw[drawOpts] (axis cs:{-2/sqrt(3)},-2,0)--(axis cs:{-2/sqrt(3)},-2,\CoordZ);
            \fill[gray] (axis cs:{-2/sqrt(3)},-2,\CoordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$x^2$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\CoordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \draw[drawOpts] (axis cs:0,-2,0)--(axis cs:0,-2,\CoordZ);
            \fill[gray] (axis cs:0,-2,\CoordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$xy$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn6}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\CoordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \draw[drawOpts] (axis cs:{2/sqrt(3)},-2,0)--(axis cs:{2/sqrt(3)},-2,\CoordZ);
            \fill[gray] (axis cs:{2/sqrt(3)},-2,\CoordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$y^2$};
        \end{axis}
        \draw[dashed] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The resulting dashed lines do not go vertically to the nodes of the triangles as I wanted to have, and also the text of these `node` instances are not at the triangle nodes. I think I might be using the command `\edef` in a wrong manner.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you include only one example? It is kind of tedious to see what is doing what. And I'm not sure if the code repeats or serves other purposes

Comment: @percusse Indeed, there was quite some repetition. I have edited the code to minimize this, but I cannot avoid all repetition since I have to depict some triangles to demonstrate the problem ;).

Comment: Can you correct your code so that it compiles and also add a sketch of how the result should look.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Sorry there was indeed still a minor error in the code and it was not compiling. I added the picture how it looks now and described how it should look. Is is understandable now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The erroneous depictions seem to be caused by the use of `\draw` and `\fill` in a pgfplots `axis` environment. Replacing the

```
\draw[drawOptsA] (axis cs:0,0,0)--(axis cs:0,0,\coordZ);
\fill[gray] (axis cs:0,0,\coordZ) circle (1pt) node[nodeOptsA] {$1$};
```

commands with

```
\addplot3[drawOpts] coordinates{(0,0,0) (0,0,\CoordZ)} node[nodeOptsA] {$1$};
```

and changing the `drawOptsA` to

```
drawOptsA/.style={gray,dashed,ultra thin,mark=*,mark size=1pt}
```

we get the desired result:

[image]

For the sake of clarity, here is the corrected code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{table.txt}
NLDefn1 NLDefn2 NLDefn3 NLDefn4 NLDefn5 NLDefn6 NLDefn7 NLDefn8 NLDefn9 NLDefn10
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   2.100000000000000e-02   4.300000000000000e-02   3.900000000000000e-02   2.000000000000000e-02
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   1.000000000000000e-02   1.750000000000000e-02   1.000000000000000e-02   5.525000000000000e-02   6.700000000000000e-02   7.325000000000000e-02   5.500000000000000e-02
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   1.333333333333333e-02   3.733333333333334e-02   1.333333333333333e-02   6.344444444444444e-02   6.811111111111111e-02   8.366666666666667e-02   6.333333333333334e-02
0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   0.000000000000000e+00   2.487500000000000e-02   5.212500000000000e-02   2.750000000000000e-02   6.018750000000000e-02   7.137499999999999e-02   8.506250000000000e-02   5.756250000000000e-02
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\fillOpacity}{0.5}
\newcommand{\textOpacity}{1}

\pgfplotsset
{   
    patchOptsA/.style={patch,mesh,patch type=triangle,gray,ultra thin},
    patchOptsB/.style={patch,patch type=triangle},
    patchOptsC/.style={patch,patch type=triangle,mesh,black},
}

\tikzset
{
        drawOptsA/.style={gray,dashed,ultra thin,mark=*,mark size=1pt},
        nodeOptsA/.style={black,anchor=south,fill=white,fill opacity=0.25,text opacity=1}
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   
            width=0.5*210mm,
            height=0.25*297mm,
            %yscale=?,
            axis lines=center,
            xmin=-4/sqrt(3),
            xmax=4/sqrt(3),
            xtick=\empty,
            hide x axis,
            %xlabel=$x$,
            ytick=\empty,
            hide y axis,
            %ylabel=$y$,
            zmin=0,
            zmax=0.1,
            view={215}{10},
        ]
            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(0,0,0) (-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (1/sqrt(3),-1,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn1}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-6_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(0,0,\triangleCoordAz) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordBz) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(0,0,\triangleCoordAz) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordBz) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,\triangleCoordCz)};

            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (-2/sqrt(3),-2,0) (0,-2,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn4}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}          
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (-2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordBz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (-2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordBz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordCz)};          

            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (0,-2,0) (1/sqrt(3),-1,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(-1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordCz)};

            \addplot3[patchOptsA] coordinates {(1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (0,-2,0) (2/sqrt(3),-2,0)}; % Reference xy plane.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordBz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn6}\of{\currfiledir table.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordCz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[patchOptsB] coordinates {(1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordCz)};
            \addplot3[patchOptsC] coordinates {(1/sqrt(3),-1,\triangleCoordAz) (0,-2,\triangleCoordBz) (2/sqrt(3),-2,\triangleCoordCz)};

            % Dashed lines and nodes of triangle.
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn1}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-4_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\coordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[drawOptsA] coordinates{(0,0,0) (0,0,\coordZ)} node[nodeOptsA]{$1$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn2}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-4_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\coordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[drawOptsA] coordinates{({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,0) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,\coordZ)} node[nodeOptsA] {$x$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn3}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-4_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\coordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[drawOptsA] coordinates{({1/sqrt(3)},-1,0) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,\coordZ)} node[nodeOptsA] {$y$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn4}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-4_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\coordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[drawOptsA] coordinates{({-2/sqrt(3)},-2,0) ({-2/sqrt(3)},-2,\coordZ)} node[nodeOptsA] {$x^2$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn5}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-4_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\coordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[drawOptsA] coordinates{(0,-2,0) (0,-2,\coordZ)} node[nodeOptsA] {$xy$};

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{NLDefn6}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_tol=1e-4_ef=poly0-3.txt}
            \edef\coordZ{\pgfplotsretval}
            \addplot3[drawOptsA] coordinates{({2/sqrt(3)},-2,0) ({2/sqrt(3)},-2,\coordZ)} node[nodeOptsA] {$y^2$};
        \end{axis}
        \draw[dashed] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```